# Force Python package setup.py bdist_wheel to include binaries in subdirectories

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a Python package that includes `bin_win32`, `bin_win64`, `bin_osx`, `bin_lnx32`, and `bin_lnx64` subdirectories with binaries for the appropriate platforms, which I call through the Python file `steamcloud.py`. When I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal`, the generated wheel does not include the files in those subdirectories, only the Python file. How can I get these included in the wheel?

Note: I'm aware 1) that the `--universal` flag is meant for Python-only packages and 2) that I should be creating separate wheels for each platform. However, I don't have access to Windows or Linux computers for development, and there is no naming convention for Linux-specific wheels.

The contents of `setup.py` can be found [here](https://github.com/aarzee/airship/blob/master/airship.steamcloud/setup.py).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first issue is that your project doesn't follow the expected layout, so you need to call `setup()` with the `package_dir` argument in addition to the `packages` and `package_data` arguments (See [installing package data](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-installing-package-data)).

```
package_dir={'airship': '<path_to_package>/airship'}
```

However, the files you're trying to include aren't really package data, so you probably don't want to add them to `package_data` like you currently are. `package_data` interprets paths relative to your packages, not relative to the project root. Instead, use [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) so you can provide paths relative to your setup.py file.